# Visual Studio C# Code Lens - why are references listed for properties but not fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, codelens

In Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, I noticed that for any class properties (w/ get/set), the Code Lens lists the number of references right above the property. But for class fields, this is not true. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Does anyone know why? Or how I can get Visual Studio to also list references for fields?

Comment: You can always right click and select Find All References for fields.

Comment: I guess this is because of performance reasons. Most of the time you dont have or change sooo much references for propertys, but fields are used very often (even more by compiler generated code). Maniging such a huge map of references should be perf crititcal.